# cannot at all find sql instance (while installing an asp.net app on IIS)

Tags: sql-server, iis-6, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003-r2, database-connection

So I'm really not a DBA, I'm an app dev.

I had to install my asp.net mvc3 app on my client's(a large company) IIS6 + Win2k3 machine, with absolutely no help from their sysadmins.

The final problem now is SQL Server 2008 r2, after figuring out how to create a login from windows, my app and sqlcmd.exe always complains it **cannot find a sql server instance**!!

I have all the sql services (in services.msc) running to Log On as the local system. I can login fine with SQL Server Management Studio with Windows Auth. I created my database, my asp.net app needs/uses windows auth.

But for the love of God, whatever I do my app always complains it cannot find the instance. (Also tried running SQL CMD and it complains of the same thing too!)

My data base connection string looks like this:

> Data Source=**machinename\username**;Initial Catalog=myDataStore;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Machinename\user is the same thing that shows up on the sql server management studio login if I choose windows authentication right?

Comment: "no help from their sysadmins." -> why? If you installed SQL Server on my network you'd be escorted out

Comment: lol!, these guys are a little crazy! I was trying to explain to one of them he hasn't given my username permissions, he kept arguing with me, then I walk him through creating the DB on his a/c, he does it with his sysadmin a/c, of course, it works!, and then he just gives me his sysadmin username and password!!

Comment: Im not bad-mouthing sysadmins, just, these guys here, are just lost at everything! They don't seem to know what they're doing, and I have to resort to google for all the server/IIS config, and most of the time it has to do with something they didn't configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Instance Name :

In SQL Server Management Studio > RegisterServers > double click your server to open the Object Explorer > right click to select the properties window > General Tab: to see the ServerName (instance name)

or Open a new query in SQL Server Management window  and execute the following

-- to get the sql server instance name

`select @@ServerName`

Default instance datasource:

`Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=myDataStore;...`

or

`Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDataStore;...`

or

`Data Source=machinename;Initial Catalog=myDataStore;...`

Comment: +1 thanks so much. I'm not seeing the Register Servers menu/option anywhere, is it because I'm on express?

Comment: in Management Studio click on Database Engine, the Connect to Server dialog box opens > Options > Registered Servers tab.

Answer (score 1):

you are using integrated authentication, so you don't have to provide even the username.
it's machinname\sqlinstancename not the username

Comment: ah, excuse my ignorance, so how do I check for the `sqlinstancename`, assuming its not `sqlexress`

Comment: you can use osql -L. If it's the default instance name, just set the computername without any \name.